# Rails: after_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Scenario: I upload a new attachment to a post that already has an attachment. (uploading directly to `s3`)

If I delete a post, then I can use `after_destroy` to delete the item within the post. But what if I simply update the post's item. I tried `after_update` (then a method to delete item) but it deletes the recent uploaded item instead of my old one. How can I get that old item deleted & not the new one?

Comment: Once you have updated the table row then `delete_item` will get the newly updated item there, hence it will delete the new item. To delete the old item you may need to use `before_update`.

Comment: I thought I already tried this but it makes sense, so I'll test it out @Manoj **edit** here's the problem with that & my first solution-- if I just want to edit the post's title, it will delete my item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `after_update` callback you can use methods `item_changed?` to check if it was changed and `item_was` for previous value.

See [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) for reference.

Comment: Worked like a charm. First time hearing about "ActiveModel::Dirty". Thank you @Yuriy :)